# FeathersJS: Injecting HTTP headers in Service Test

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

In a feathersJS service, I have a `before` hook being ran that expects a certain HTTP header to exist:

**src/services/service_name/service_name.hooks.js**

```
const validationHook = () => (context, next) => {
  if (!context.params.headers.hasOwnProperty('header-wanted'))
    throw new errors.BadRequest();
  next(null, context);
};

module.exports = {
    before: {
        all: [cronValidationHook()],
...
..
.
```

When testing this service in a generated test file from `feathers-cli`, however, I haven't found a way to inject headers prior to the before hook being called. The test in question is:

**test/services/service_name.test.js**

```
describe('get', () => {
  it('should run "id" endpoint', async () => {
    const service = app.service('v1/cron');
    const resp = await service.get('id', params);
    // Assertions exist after this call
   });
});
```

Is there a way to do this that does not require utilizing an HTTP call via `node-fetch` or `requests`?

Comment: Couldn't you add them to `params` in your `service.get` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` will be whatever you pass. Just set `params.headers` to what you would like to test, e.g.

```js
const getParams =  {
   ...params,
   headers: { 'header-wanted': 'something' }
};
const resp = await service.get('id', getParams);
```